# in zk mvc I want to iterate on a list

Tags: java, zk

I have a program in zk and i need to use mvc to set up details of a listbox. In my model I have a user who has an id, a username, a password and a set of roles (a role is an enum). In my controller a fill in the `ListModelList<User>`

In the zul I have the following code:

```
<template name="model">
    <listitem >
        <listcell label="${each.idUser}"></listcell>
        <listcell label="${each.username}"></listcell>
        <listcell label="${each.password}"></listcell>
        <listcell label="${each.roles}"></listcell>
    </listitem> 
</template>
```

Now I don't wanne put each.roles, but I want to but true if the set of roles contains for example Role.ADMIN

How do I do that? I tried

```
<listcell label="${each.roles.contains(Role.ADMIN)}"></listcell>
```

but that give me always false, although some users has the role of ADMIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you can execute functions like `contains` from [ZK's Expression Language (EL)](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/EL_Expressions).

Instead, you'll want to wrap this `contains(Role.ADMIN)` logic in a function that seems more like a getter. Try this:

```
<listcell label="${each.isAdmin}"></listcell>
```

With a getter for `isAdmin` added to your model object:

```
public boolean getIsAdmin() {
    return roles.contains(Role.ADMIN);
}
```

This may seem like a little more work, but I think it actually goes a long way in separating the view from the business logic. Little things like this make your views more declarative and easier to read, while keeping the complexity in Java where you can easily test it.